# get Crawler engine status outside reactor

Tags: python, web-scraping, process, scrapy

I'm launching a process crawler in order to collect items:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=crawlerprocess

Then i have to monitor progression of the process from a django application and set value of progression in redis store and also the status of crawler to on.

My ask is how to hook the process when it is killed or stopped
to update status in redis

Is it possible to trigger a function like signal but for SIGKILL when process is interrupted like:

```
crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_interrupted, signal=signals.engine_stopped)
```

doc:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=signals

Comment: please create a [mre] and provide further explanation of what you are asking

Comment: Alexander i've edited my asking and use case